# Mapstruct mapping optional field with nested collection

Tags: java, spring-boot, mapstruct

```
public class Parent {
    private List<Children> childrens = new ArrayList<>();
    //setter && getter
}


public class Children{

    private Employee employee;
    //setter && getter

}

public class ChildrenDTO{
    private String employeeId;
    private String employeeName;
    ......
}

public class Employee{
    private String id;
    private String name;
    .....
}



@Mapper
public interface ParentMapper{
    ParentDTO toDto(Parent parent);
}
```

I have used `mapstruct` to map the `Parent` entity to `ParentDTO`, then my question is: 
How can I map `employee` to be `employeeId` and `employeeName` in ChildrenDTO when calling `parrentMapper.toDto` method?

I have checked an example from https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples, but it seems they don't have my case.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Also add your DTO so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.baeldung.com/mapstruct

```
@Mapper
public interface EmployeeMapper {
    @Mappings({
      @Mapping(target="employeeId", source="entity.id"),
      @Mapping(target="employeeName", source="entity.name")
    })
    EmployeeDTO employeeToEmployeeDTO(Employee entity);
    @Mappings({
      @Mapping(target="id", source="dto.employeeId"),
      @Mapping(target="name", source="dto.employeeName")
    })
    Employee employeeDTOtoEmployee(EmployeeDTO dto);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple ways doing it. What you can prefer for readibility is mentioned below

```
    @Mapping(target = "targetFieldFromParentDto", source = "sourceField", qualifiedByName = "abstractMethodWithFurtherMappers")
    public abstract ParentDTO toChildrenDto(Parent parent);


    @Mapping(target = "employee", source = "employeeID"
    @Named("abstractMethodWithFurtherMappers")
    public abstract Employee abstractMethodWithFurtherMappers(Childrens ch);
```

Also if you don't want to use `qualifiedByName= "methodName"` then you can use `expressions` example

```
expression = "java(toMethodWithBody(param1, param2))"
```

Let me know if you need more clarity.